# Clojure: Dynamic form loading in enlive-html

Tags: clojure

i need to load a checkbox dynamically and set its state based on some value....

This is what i have done so far...

```
(defsnippet customer-config-setup html-customer-configuration [:div#div_game_setup_container ]
  [result-rows]
  [:div#div_gameprefix]
  (clone-for [idv (map vector (iterate inc 0) result-rows)]
    [:button#btn_gameprefix ]
    (do->

    #(if (= (result-rows :active) 0)
       ((set-attr :checked  :val )%)%)
      (content (str ((idv 1) :gameprefix )))

    )
  )

)
```

and also

```
(defsnippet customer-config-approval html-customer-configuration [:div#div_auto_approval ]
  [result-rows]
  [:tr#tr_auto_approval]
  (clone-for [idv (map vector (iterate inc 0) result-rows)]
    [:td#td_auto_approvaltext ] (content (str ((idv 1) :settings_caption )))
    [:td#td_auto_checkbox ] (set-attr :checked  :val )
    )
  )
```

but for some reason they don't work... what could be the problem.... and is there a way to set checkbox state here.....?

Thank you..

Comment: I have trouble understanding the context: for the first snippet, what is result-rows, what are you trying to accomplish with the clone-for etc. (Why are you numbering the rows and not using the data?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i had missed out something.. 
adding `(((idv 1))` while getting values here is necessary... i really don't have enough time to dig up and find a reason why is that even required... because this `library/clojure` is so low on resources and tutorials it becomes hard find a reason for such things...

```
(defsnippet customer-config-setup html-customer-configuration [:div#div_game_setup_container ]
  [result-rows]
  [:div#div_gameprefix]
  (clone-for [idv (map vector (iterate inc 0) result-rows)]
    [:button#btn_gameprefix ]
    (do->

    #(if (= (((idv 1)result-rows :active)) 0)
       ((set-attr :checked  :val )%)%)
      (content (str ((idv 1) :gameprefix )))

    )
  )

)
```